# Issue with List(); function by Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to list all the images from my Firebase storage to app. I know the method of adding images to storage and adding links to database but my client is unaware of this. So when i found that Firebase currently allows to list all the images from a folder. I've been working on this from last two days but no luck.

My Activity Code:

```
public class Events_and_Participations extends AppCompatActivity {

    StorageReference reference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Images_Adapter adapter;
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    Button button;
    FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_and_participations);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(R.string.item_title_4);

        button = findViewById(R.id.login);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (user == null){
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images");

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> auth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Loading..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }));

        if (user != null){
            reference.listAll()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {

                        for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                            items.add(item.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(Events_and_Participations.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
        }



        adapter = new Images_Adapter(items);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.events_photos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}
```

My Storage Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/sahrudhaya-foundation.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write : if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you authenticate before call reference.list(10)?

Comment: Yes I did...!! It just shows me a empty screen and nothing else not even error

Comment: I Found the issue, when the .getDownloadUrl(); is called it doesn't returns a string url instead it returns a package name like com.google.package.gms.task@z1562646 blah.. blah.. Now help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDownloadUrl()` doesn't return an `Uri` directly but a `Task<Uri>`. You have to add a callback, with `addOnSuccessListener()` and `addOnFailureListener()` to be notified with the actual value (like you did with the list itself).

You can also use `addOnCompleteListener` to handle both success and failure cases.